# Xamarin firing OnAppearing event in wrong page after close browser

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

`OnAppearing`  Called at wrong page after close browser `Browser.OpenAsync`

I would like to describe the scenario :
I have 2 pages  
Main `Home.xaml` 
Sub `ItemDetailPage.xaml`

When I Select an item from List in `Home.xaml` I do the following:

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var item = args.SelectedItem as SelectedItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?ItemId={item.Id}");
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

In the page `ItemDetailPage.xaml` I clicked `GoToLink` method

```
private async void GoToLink(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             await Browser.OpenAsync($"https://website.com/");
        }
```

The browser opened without any issue until I close it the code will call `OnAppearing()` related to `Home.xaml` page and keep `ItemDetailPage.xaml` page focused, Then I press back in `ItemDetailPage.xaml`

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
```

The screen back to `Home.xaml` page but without calling `OnAppearing()`

Comment: Try to use` "//{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?ItemId={item.Id}" ` . Prefixing with `//` switches to a different navigation stack instead of pushing to the active one .

Comment: Thank you for suggestion I tried this but unfortunately same result

Comment: I created a basic demo to test the function code code and reproduced the issue. The **OnAppearing** method will be called after closing the broswer. After test, it turns out that the OnDisappearing method of ItemDetailPage will not be called when opening the browser. Try to detect the ItemDetailPage's **OnDisappearing** method instead of the Home page's OnAppearing method.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT Thank you for your effort I tested what you suggested and yes   OnDisappearing  will be called after close ItemDetailPage  but the problem is that I need to reflect the result on Home page after finished from ItemDetailPage , so calling OnAppearing before i finish from ItemDetailPage  will not reflect new result , Thanks

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT I solve this issue by work-around solution by using MessagingCenter after calling OnDisappearing() from ItemDetailPage i'm using MessagingCenter.Send and handle new result in Home page

Comment: Congrats! Please post the solution as an answer and accept it. It will be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT I do thank you for contributing in solving this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do workaround for this problem   
by using [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

AS following:

After close `ItemDetailPage.xaml` the only event occur in this page was `OnDisappearing()`

So before opened the browser I do create a flag `IsBrowserOpened`  **`(Static variable)`**

`ItemDetailPage.xaml` :

```
        private async void GoToLink(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             IsBrowserOpened= true;
             await Browser.OpenAsync($"https://website.com/");
        }
        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            if (IsBrowserOpened)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, "updateFromBrowser", 1);
            }
        }
```

`Home.xaml` Page

```
public partial class Home : ContentPage
    {

        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ItemDetailPage, int>(this, "updateFromBrowser", async (obj, item) =>
            {
                // Update home page for incoming new data

            });

        }
}
```